error: src/main.tsx: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes') Nx monorepo ios/ android app runtime error
I am creating an nx monorepo for react and react native app.
Monorepo is setup successfully and building successfully on react/ios/android.
On running, it is giving error.
src/main.tsx: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
Main.tsx code:
 import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './app/App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Mobileapp', () => App);

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.
Regards,
Gypsa

need steps on how you've setup the monorepo

I have followed the url: https://medium.com/ascentic-technology/one-codebase-for-react-and-react-native-with-nx-monorepos-5e876ed829c2

I found the solution:
https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/22665
The answer "Comment the condition of build on .babelrc.js" works for me.
Commenting below code in babelrc.js
/* if (
process.env.NX_TASK_TARGET_TARGET === 'build' ||
process.env.NX_TASK_TARGET_TARGET.includes('storybook')
) {
return {
presets: [
[
'@nx/react/babel',
{
runtime: 'automatic',
},
],
],
};
}*/
